Folder structure conflict of Expo react native app with FSD v.2
I want to use FSD v2 with Expo application. As Expo application uses file based routing like a next.js,  there is some conflicts. However, I found that there is possibilities to solve according to Docs FSD. At some point it seems to solve it, the outer app folder will not be used with expo router as it will read only src/app first if it exists. The src/app directory takes higher precedence than the root app directory. Only the src/app directory will be used if you have both.. What should I do in that case?

in my project we just created app-root folder with all of the providers, interceptors, etc.
So, the all routing / session initialization logic is living in src/app folder, but all FSD stuff is living inside src/app-root folder.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
